# Trying to compare datetime to current in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, select

I'm trying to set a time stamp, and only pull back records that have waited 15 minutes on a retry system.
Basically, i want to say select where RETRY_TMSTAMP + 15 minutes > NOW.
RETRY_TMSTAMP is a DATETIME type.

```
SELECT r.id from Blah.GREAT_TABLE r 
WHERE r.RETRY_TMSTAMP < ______________;
```

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: One simple method is something like `sysdate + 15 / (24*60)`

Comment: i want to compare my RETRY_TMSTAMP + 15 to the sysdate. can you show me how i would do this?

Comment: So you need to add 15 minutes to your timestamp column.. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. And compare it to SYSDATE. Like this...
WHERE r.RETRY_TMSTMP < SYSDATE + 10/1440

But i do not know how to use SYSDATE. 
It looks like i have to do a separate select for SYSDATE like this,


     select sysdate, sysdate+1/24, sysdate +1/1440, sysdate + 1/86400         from dual

Comment: (By the way, apparently SYSDATE + 10/1440 is SYSDATE + 10 minutes, so I know that part, i just don't know how to throw this all together.

Answer (score 2):

> Basically, i want to say select where RETRY_TMSTAMP + 15 minutes > NOW

```
SELECT r.id
FROM   Blah.GREAT_TABLE r 
WHERE  r.RETRY_TMSTAMP + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE > SYSDATE;
```

Or

```
SELECT r.id
FROM   Blah.GREAT_TABLE r 
WHERE  r.RETRY_TMSTAMP + 15/(24*60) > SYSDATE;
```

Comment: Thanks this should do it! :)

Comment: Good answer, but I'd suggest `r.retry_tmstmp > SYSDATE - 15/(24*40)`, to allow Oracle to take advantage of any index on `r.retry_tmstmp`.

Comment: _timestamp_ is a different datatype than _date_ (of which sysdate belongs) so there's typecasting. To be clear, use the same math with timestamp on the right-side of the comparison to leverage any index on retry_tmstmp. So the comparison becomes `r.retry_tmstmp > systimestamp - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE`

Comment: @Beege From the OP's question: `RETRY_TMSTAMP is a DATETIME type.` That could be either a `DATE` or a `TIMESTAMP` as both have a date and time component.

Comment: @MTO Agreed that `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` are both called _datetime_ data types, so we don't know from the OP which specific data type we're working with, but they are NOT the same data type. `TIMESTAMP` is actually an extension of the `DATE` data type. So I think my comment about typecasting still applies.